# C++ transferring variables between functions

Tags: c++

I'm not quite sure what I messed up here. I'm making a basic program that converts Fahrenheit to celsius. I can't figure out how to transfer the f variable over to the calcC function. All that I'm getting is a prompt for Fahrenheit and then it tells me that it is 0 degrees celsius.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function prototypes

double getF();
double calcC();

int main(){

    // declare variables
    double f = 0.0;
    double c = 0.0;

    // call getF
    getF();

    // call CalcC
    calcC();

    cout << c << " degrees celsius." << endl;

    return 0;
} // end of main function

// function definitions

double getF(){

    double f = 0.0;
    
    // prompt user
    cout << "Enter farenheit: ";
    cin >> f;
    return f;
} // end of getF function

double calcC(){

    double c = 0.0;
    double f = 0.0;

    // calculate celsius
    c = (5 / 9) * f;

    return c;
} // end of calcC function
```

I should also note that I'm pretty new at this, so I apologize if I'm making a really stupid mistake.

Comment: Hint: Where do you store the values returned by your functions?

Comment: Your C++ textbook should have a chapter on functions that explains and shows examples of calling functions with parameters. Is there something in that chapter that's unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return values of `getF()` and `calcC()`, and you are not passing anything at all to `calcC()`.

`calcC()` is performing *integer arithmetic* on `(5 / 9)`, which will result in `0`, not `0.555...` as your formula requires. You need to use *floating-point arithmetic* instead. Also, your formula is wrong, as you need to subtract 32 from the farenheit. So, even if you were to pass a value into `calcC()`, you will not get the correct result.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getF();
double calcC(double);

int main() {
    double f = getF();
    double c = calcC(f);
    cout << c << " degrees celsius." << endl;
    return 0; 
}

double getF() {
    double f = 0.0;
    cout << "Enter farenheit: ";
    cin >> f;
    return f;
}

double calcC(double f) {
    return (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write :

```
double getF(){

    double f = 0.0;
    
    // prompt user
    cout << "Enter farenheit: ";
    cin >> f;
    return f;
} // end of getF function
```

you return a double, here f, as you know. The thing is, when you return something, you have to keep it somewhere, otherwise, it is lost.

So, when you return f, but you don't store what this function is returning, you loose f. To avoid that, here is what you should do.

```
double takemyvalue = getF();
```

In your main function. With this line of code, what you are saying is :
"I declare a variable named "takemyvalue", and in this variable, I store what is returned by the function getF()"

And then, you can send takemyvalue as a parameter of your next function, so you have to say to the next function that it needs a parameter to operate correctly, and to use this parameter. The functionning code should be :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function prototypes

double getF();
double calcC(double);

int main(){

    // declare variables
    double f = 0.0;
    double c = 0.0;

    // call getF
    double takemyvalue = getF();

    // call CalcC
    double c = calcC(takemyvalue);

    cout << c << " degrees celsius." << endl;

    return 0;
} // end of main function

// function definitions

double getF(){

    double f = 0.0;
    
    // prompt user
    cout << "Enter farenheit: ";
    cin >> f;
    return f;
} // end of getF function

double calcC(double myvalue){

    double c = 0.0;
    double f = myvalue;

    // calculate celsius
    c = (5 / 9) * f;

    return c;
} // end of calcC function
```

That should do what you want, but I didn't test it

Comment: The declaration of `f` doesn't seem very useful now that you've replaced it with `takemyvalue`. Your second declaration of `c` makes the program ill-formed.

Comment: You're right. I wanted to keep the shape of his code that way he should be able to understand how to program a little bit easier with the changes I've made. The author is obviously very new, so I didn't want to make this harder

Comment: You could have used OP:s variable `f` if you wanted to make it easy. When you added a duplicate declaration of `c` you also made the program ill-formed which _does_ make it harder.

Answer (score 0):

You can take they values of Main, anda later sent them from parámetros yo te funcions getF anda calcC